# Why the Xcode 8.2.1 explicit version does not appear at Apple Developer Download?

Tags: install, xcode, software-update, software

For a MacBookPro with `El Capitan` - **10.11.6**.

About `Xcode`, according with [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com) the latest acceptable release is:

- ***Xcode 8.2.1** for macOS 10.11.5+*

Once logged on Apple Developer at https://developer.apple.com/download/all if is used as *search criteria*:

- **Command Line Tools 8.2.1**: does not appear a result
- **Command Line Tools 8.2**: appears among many results the `Command Line Tools (macOS 10.11) for Xcode 8.2` result
- **Command Line Tools 10.11.6**: does not appear a result
- **Command Line Tools 10.11**: appears among many results the `Command Line Tools (macOS 10.11) for Xcode 8.2` result

For the same result if is expanded `View Details`, it shows some generic info and indicates that the *.dmg* file has a size of *147.51MB*

Now, at [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com) the ***Xcode 8.2.1** for macOS 10.11.5+* record has the `Download` link which targets to download the [Xcode_8.2.1.xip](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.2.1/Xcode_8.2.1.xip) file. If the web browser starts to download, it has a size of *4.2GB*

Currently my Mac has `Xcode` with the `8.2.0.0.1.1480973914` version

**Question**

- Why the `Xcode` **8.2.1** explicit version does not appear at *Apple Developer Download*?

**Extra Questions**

- Should I download the `Xcode_8.2.1.xip` or *.dmg* (8.2 version) file?
- Why the huge difference about sizes? *147.51MB* vs *4.2GB*
- Does my mac really have the latest `Xcode` 8.2 version? I am not sure if `8.2.0.0.1.1480973914` is the same available as the *.dmg* file

Comment: 'Why' is probably because there is little to no active curation of releases so far behind supported versions. El Capitan went out of support 5 years ago. You're trying to find something Apple simply ceased caring about a long time ago.

Comment: Even when you are correct, `Xcode` **8.2** was available at `12 Dec 2016` and the **8.2.1** was available at `19 Dec 2016` just 7 days later. So the latter should available too in the results

Comment: Just for the record, I installed the `.dmg` file mentioned, the version returned is the same - `8.2.0.0.1.1480973914`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The https://developer.apple.com/download/all page works as expected.

It was a confusion of terms by my side (*consequence of many hours of work*), if the *search criteria* is used as:

- Either `Command Line Tools 8.2` or `Command Line Tools 10.11` returns among many results the *Command Line Tools (macOS 10.11) for **Xcode 8.2*** result
- `Xcode 8.2.1` that returns as unique result the expected **Xcode 8.2.1** mentioned at [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com)

Therefore is different *Command Line Tools (macOS 10.11) for **Xcode 8.2*** vs **Xcode 8.2.1**. Therefore as conclusion the `Xcode` term appears alone - and within the `Command Line Tools` term