# How to update Xcode to the latest acceptable version according with the current OS? It directly by command (without Homebrew)

Tags: command-line, xcode, software-update, upgrade

In Linux `Ubuntu` for example with the commands:

- `sudo apt update && upgrade`

is possible update the complete set of current software already installed. I know the same approach is possible for Mac **but** through `Homebrew` (I am assuming the same for `MacPorts` too).

I am with this situation:

- [Why the Xcode 8.2.1 explicit version does not appear at Apple Developer Download?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449326/why-the-xcode-8-2-1-explicit-version-does-not-appear-at-apple-developer-download)

So, Is possible do the same approach about update `Xcode` **directly** by command? I mean, without `Homebrew`. I don't have installed `MacPorts`. Therefore I am wondered if instead to do the process by searching and installing manually, exists a command(s), something like:

```
xcode update --check
xcode update
```

It to let quickly check (if exists or not an update) for the current OS version (`El Capitan` 10.11.6) and if is exists then finally update `Xcode`.

I want install `MacPorts` in an old mac and to be safe I want install the latest acceptable version of `Xcode`

**Question**

- How to update `Xcode` to the latest acceptable version according with the current OS? It directly by command (without Homebrew)

Comment: There isn’t an incremental update available for Xcode, it is just too big and interconnected.  The only official site is Apple’s Developer Downloads, which does not include all releases, such as beta and bug fix versions.  If all you need are the command line tools (compiler, linker, headers, etc), that download is quite a bit smaller.  Note that if you are wanting to deploy to the App Store, current versions of Xcode are required, which require current versions of macOS.

Comment: @red_menace thanks for the comment, the purpose is install `MacPorts` in peace, so I want be sure I have the latest acceptable version of `Xcode` for the current old `macOS`. According with your comment - seems it the unique way is manually (without command(s)). Am I correct?

Comment: Correct - download the .xip or .dmg from the Developer site and use that.  MacPorts (or Homebrew) are completely different (and separate) utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** a command approach - but is totally safe use the https://developer.apple.com/download/all page - it works as expected. It shows all the result available.

If the *search criteria* is used as:

- Either `Command Line Tools 8.2` or `Command Line Tools 10.11` returns among many results the *Command Line Tools (macOS 10.11) for **Xcode 8.2*** result - which represents the `Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.11_for_Xcode 8.2.dmg` file with a size of *147.51MB*
- `Xcode 8.2.1` that returns as unique result the expected **Xcode 8.2.1** mentioned at [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com) - which represents the `Xcode_8.2.1.xip` file with a size of *4.2GB*

Therefore there are two files:

- *Command Line Tools* for *Xcode*
- *Xcode* itself.